# CF7 upload file failing

Tags: posts, uploads, forms, http

So I've been trying to solve this for days now but just don't get it.
I have a form on a Wordpress site (Contact form 7) where a user can fill in some data and submit it, this will then create a post in a custom post type. All of this works fine. The problem is by the end of the form there's a file attachment field. And the files aren't ending up in my Wordpress library nor is it even ending up on the server.

My form looks like this:

```
[select* pri_act_type include_blank "Value1" "Value2" "Value3" "Value4"]

[text* pri_act_name placeholder "Your name"]

[email* pri_act_email placeholder "Your email address"]

... A bunch of fields here ...

[file image limit:10000000 filetypes:jpg|jpeg|png|gif]

[submit "Send"]
```

The function that hooks into the submission and creates the post and finally tries to upload the file looks like this:

```
function action_wpcf7_before_send_mail( $contact_form ) {

    $wpcf = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
    if ($wpcf->id == 120) {
    $wpcf->skip_mail = true;

    ***..... <A bunch of code that creates the post> ......***

        // Upload file
        if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        }

        $uploadedfile = $_FILES['image'];

        $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );

        $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );

        if ( $movefile && ! isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
            $status_message = "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
            $vatt = var_dump( $movefile );
        } else {
            /**
             * Error generated by _wp_handle_upload()
             * @see _wp_handle_upload() in wp-admin/includes/file.php
             */
            $status_message = $movefile['error'];
        }
    }
};
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'action_wpcf7_before_send_mail', 10, 1 );
```

Now the problem is, this part: `if ( $movefile && ! isset( $movefile['error'] ) )` always fails. The ***$movefile['error'];*** is always:

> Specified file failed upload test.

When I debug it on my local server I come all the way down to this:

```
$test_uploaded_file = 'wp_handle_upload' === $action ? @ is_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'] ) : @ is_file( $file['tmp_name'] );
    if ( ! $test_uploaded_file ) {
        return call_user_func_array( $upload_error_handler, array( &$file, __( 'Specified file failed upload test.' ) ) );
    }
```

This is where the error is thrown. I'm pretty sure the problem is that *is_uploaded_file()* fails. This is what's given to it from *$file['tmp_name']*:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Screen Shot 2018-03-12 at 12.42.43.png
    [type] => image/png
    [tmp_name] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/php9ej3tB
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 33177
)
```

So when I look it up in the PHP docs it says:

> The is_uploaded_file() function checks whether the specified file is
>   uploaded via HTTP POST.
>
> This function returns TRUE if the file is uploaded via HTTP POST.

But I'm not sure what this means. How is it NOT uploaded via HTTP POST? Or am I missing something obvious here? I've tried uploading files via the admin page (Media library) and tried running this on a proper server and not just my local env. But nothing works. Help!

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress StackExchange! Usually, questions exclusively regarding 3rd party plugins is [considered to be off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and better asked using their respective support methods. Please [take the tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more. Check out the [Contact Form 7 Support Forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/contact-form-7).

Comment: there has to be something else going on, as Howdy_McGee says, it is probably best to ask CF7 support forum.

Comment: btw the error seems to indicate that the file you try to process was not uploaded at that session.

Comment: Ok thanks guy, I wasn't sure the error was due to CF7, will ask there. I'll try to look up what you said about sessions @MarkKaplun, thanks!